# How can I see the jquerymobile source code generated with a template?

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, debugging, jquery-mobile

I have CSS issues on JQuery mobile pages generated via JSPs.

Because, end of multiple processing HTML result is unreadable, I'd like to read the result of the JSP processing in order to compare the JQM code with the JQM code given by the designer.

Therefore, its ***not*** the result of JSP to Java servlet that interests me.

Say I have a code like this exagerated resumé

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
<c:forEach items="${laListe}" var="curseur">
   <c:if test=""><div class="blue" ></c:if>
   <c:if test=""><div class="red" ></c:if>
```

I'd like to know what is the HTML+JQM code that will be interpreted by JQ+JQM in the browser, and what div is chosen.

Thank you

Comment: Can you "view source" the page?

Comment: @Salman A yes but the generated html is a mess, its what is interpreted by jqm, that I want to read. Before the magic happens.

Answer (score 0):

The point is to read the JQM code generated by a template, before it is interpreted, processed by JQM and expanded to the point of being unreadable.

The options I found are :

- use CURL
- with chrome

  - open developper console (inspect element, anywhere on page)
  - click 'Network' tab
  - find the page between all elements loaded (css, pics, ...). Top of list
  - click it
  - go to Preview tab
- with Firefox

  - use Firebug